# How to get an invitation letter for a Romanian tourist visa?

Tags: visas, applications, romania, invitation-letters, iraqi-citizens

Please who can help me in getting an invitation letter for visiting Romania as a tourist by guiding me to a travel agency that can provide me with the letter?

I'm Iraqi and live in Iraq.

Comment: Who is inviting you? An invitation can be obtained ONLY with the help of the persons / institutions that invite you to Romania. See http://evisa.mae.ro/SupportingDocuments

Comment: To follow up on Traveller's comment: What makes you think travel agencies write these letters? Maybe the question should be: *Can I get an invitation letter from a travel agency for visiting Romania as a tourist?*

Comment: @JanDoggen Following the link in Traveller's comment, there is the text "Invitations can be made, for each invited third-state national, by Romanian travel agencies,"

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold for now.